# Best practise for a website hosted on Kubernetes (DigitalOcean)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I followed this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes on how to setup an Nginx Ingress with Cert Manager with Kubernetes having DigitalOcean as a cloud provider.

The tutorial worked fine, I was able to setup everything according to what it was written. Though, (as it is stated) following the tutorial one ends up with three pods of which only one is in "Running 1/1", while the other two are "Down". Also when checking the comments section, it seems that it is quite a problem. Since if all the traffic gets routed to only 1 pods, it is not really scalable. Or am I missing something? Quoting from their tutorial:

> Note: By default the Nginx Ingress LoadBalancer Service has
> service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy set to the value Local, which
> routes all load balancer traffic to nodes running Nginx Ingress Pods.
> The other nodes will deliberately fail load balancer health checks so
> that Ingress traffic does not get routed to them.

Mainly my question is: Is there a best practice that I am missing in order to have Kubernetes hosting my website? It seems I have to choose either scalability (having all the pods healthy and running) or getting IP of the client visitor.

Answer (score 0):

And for whoever will ever find himself/herself in my situation, this is the reply I got from the DigitaOcean Support:

> Unfortunately with that Kubernetes setup it would show those other
> nodes as down without additional traffic configuration. It is possible
> to skip the nginx ingress part and just use a DigitalOcean load
> balancer but this again does require a good deal of setup and can be
> more difficult then easy.

The suggestion to have a website with analytics (IP) and scalable was to setup a droplet with Nginx and setup a LoadBalancer to it. More specifically:

> As for using a droplet this would be a normal website configuration
> with Nginx as your webserver configured to serve content to your app.
> You would have full access to your application and the Nginx logs on
> the droplet itself. Putting a load balancer in front of this would
> require additional configuration as load balancers do not pass the
> x-forward header so the IP addresses of clients would not show up in
> the logs by default. You would need to configured proxy protocol on
> the load balancer and in your nginx configuration to be able to obtain
> those IPs.
> https://www.digitalocean.com/blog/load-balancers-now-support-proxy-protocol/
> This is also a bit more complex unfortunately.

Hope it might save some time to someone